# how to sql recursion solve first node first then move to another in CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

suppose i have a data like that

```
ID  ParentID   Name
1     null      a
2      1        b
3      2        c
4      1        d
5      4        e
```

if i use cte(common table expression) provided by sql it shows me result like this

```
ID  ParentID   Name
1     null      a
2      1        b
4      1        d
3      2        c
5      4        e
```

but i want to arrange data like, query should complete first node till end , then move to other node . like

```
ID  ParentID   Name
1     null      a
2      1        b
3      2        c
4      1        d
5      4        e
```

Note: i have a primary key with datatype :uniqueidentifier so i cannot use order by clause after CTE

Comment: Sorry the question does not make much sense, can you elaborate on your requirement please?

Comment: Use `ORDER BY ID` when selecting from your CTE. `SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY ID`

Comment: i want my data to arrange like in 3rd code example, but CTE gives me records in different order .

Comment: actually this is my mistake , but my primary key id is based on uniqueidentifier so i cannot use order by clause after CTE

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @Top   int         = null      --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 2

;with cteP as (
      Select ID
            ,ParentID 
            ,Name 
            ,Path = cast('/'+[ID]+'/' as varchar(500))
      From   YourTable 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(ParentID ,-1) else ID end
      Union  All
      Select r.ID
            ,r.ParentID 
            ,r.Name
            ,cast(p.path + '/'+r.[ID]+'/' as varchar(500))
      From   YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.ParentID  = p.ID)
Select ID
      ,ParentID
      ,Name  
 From cteP A
 Order By Path
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: but i am using uniqueidentifier  for my primary key and parent id

Comment: @FrazZaki Updated

Comment: @FrazZaki cast it as varchar in the path expressions

Comment: @FrazZaki FYI you may want to consider not using the ID in the path expression, but rather the NAME

Comment: @FrazZaki Using NAME in the path expressions may give a better, more intuitive presentation

Comment: great , working with bit conversion changes , thanks brother

Comment: @FrazZaki Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your query, I think you can do something like this:

```
WITH CTE_Example
AS
(
YOUR QUERY
)

SELECT *
FROM CTE_Example
ORDER BY ID
```